# After replacing the screen, the maximum brightness lower than it used to be

Tags: brightness

I have a Dell XPS 13 9360. I had to replace the screen (which means: I had to replace the entire top half of my laptop...) since I cracked that by mistake...

Of course, the new screen is original and it's the very same model as the previous one. Still, the maximum brightness is not as bright as the previous one.

I didn't change any file for replacing it. I simply open the case and physically replaced the screen.

I guess that the new screen has some kind of different ID and that my computer has to understand that he has to loads the very same drivers it used to load for the old screen.

I checked the `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/` folder only after the replacement, and I can read that the max_brightness is set to 7500. It looks like there's no direct way to edit that file by using a text editor.

My grub hasn't changed from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/mapper/fedora-swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet options i915 enable_fbc=1 enable_guc=3 disable_power_well=0 fastboot=1 options dell-smm-hwmon restricted=0 force=1"`

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this? I use Fedora 30.

Comment: is it the also different in bios menus?

Comment: I didn't take note of how the previous screen was listed in the BIOS, so it's hard for me to check now (also because the previous screen is really really cracked, i.e. it doesn't work anymore). I gave it for granted that "same screen model" = "no issue at all". :(

Comment: sorry, i was not clear .. i am asking about how bright the screen appears in bios menus

Comment: It's as bright as when using the OS: less bright than the old one. :(

Comment: talk to Dell then ... but first, check to make sure that the screen does not have some type of protective film that you have to peel off ... good luck

Comment: Well, yeah, it has a protective film but it's just a transparent plastic film. It doesn't make it darker. I raised a corner of that film to be sure about this.

I'm not really willing to talk to Dell people: they can't help about linux-related issues. I'm quite confident this is just a matter of loading the right driver also because the old screen minimum brightness was not 0, but now I can reach 0 usin the fn keys: this is something that got fixed on its own during some ordinary update.